# Add or remove class with prototype

Tags: class, magento, prototypejs, prototype, removeclass

Cant figure the PROTOTYPE script for adding or removing a the css class name "selected" to img element based in click function (already done for Jquery...) but it must be in Prototype. And its driving me crazy. Cant make it work for prototype....

My original code is (Magento store)

```
<div class="block block-poll">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Community Poll') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <form id="pollForm" action="<?php echo $action ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validatePollAnswerIsSelected();">
        <div class="block-content">
            <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($poll->getPollTitle()); ?></p>
            <?php if( $poll_answers ): ?>
            <ul id="poll-answers">
                <?php foreach( $poll_answers as $answer ): ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="vote" style ="display:none;" class="radio poll_vote" id="vote_<?php echo $answer->getId() ?>" value="<?php echo $answer->getAnswerId() ?>" />
                    <?php
                    $stripped = $answer->getAnswerTitle();
                    $stripped_final = str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($stripped)); //Value (simplified)
                     ?>
                    <span class="label"><label for="vote_<?php echo $answer->getId() ?>"><img src="http://www.passione.pt/media/poll/<?php echo $stripped_final; ?>.png" id="chooser" class="chooser" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($answer->getAnswerTitle()) ?>" onClick="document.getElementById('vote_<?php echo $answer->getId() ?>').checked =true;"/></label></span>         
                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('poll-answers');</script>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Vote') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Vote') ?></span></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For Jquery.

Could you transform for Prototype 1.7...?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var Chooser = $('#poll-answers img');
    Chooser.click(function() {
        $('.chooser').removeClass('selected');
        if(!Chooser.hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).addClass('selected');        
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Show us what you have in jQuery and we'll convert it to Protoype.

Comment: Added to the question my original code for Jquery. Want for prototype, please.

Comment: Try this example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_element_addclassname.htm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prototype version of that click handler (untested):

```
$('poll-answers').on('click', 'img', function(event, element) {
    $$('.chooser').invoke('removeClassName', 'selected');
    element.toggleClassName('selected');
});
```

Edit: Changed to `toggleClassName` as per @Victor's suggestion. +7 points for him, and from `each` to `invoke` thanks to @Geek Num. +7 points for him and 1 left over for me.

Comment: There is `toggleClassName()` method which will add/remove class name for you http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/toggleClassName/

Comment: for this line `$$('.chooser').each(function(i) { i.removeClassName('selected') });` you should use the `invoke()` method. Its cleaner than using each if you are going to call one function. `$$('.chooser').invoke("removeClassName","selected");` http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/invoke/

Comment: Some good examples
http://terriswallow.com/weblog/2007/evolving-styles-add-change-remove-classes-with-prototype/