# Toggle Class Prototype Function

Tags: magento, prototypejs, prototype

I'm trying to iterate over an array of elements, specified by class name. Then I want to use a function to toggle the class and change some text.

This does **NOT** work:

```
$$('.btn').forEach( setButtonLoadingStateOn, this );

setButtonLoadingStateOn = function( btn ) {
    btn.toggleClassName('loading');
    btn.disable();
    btn.select('span span')[0].update( "please wait..." );
}
```

This does **NOT** work:

```
$$('.btn').each( function(btn) {
    btn.addClassName('loading');
    btn.disable();
    btn.select('span span')[0].innerHTML = "please wait...";
});
```

This also does **NOT** work:

```
setButtonLoadingState( '.btn', 'start' );

setButtonLoadingState = function( btnClass, loadState ) {
    btnElem = $$( btnClass );

    btnElem.each(function( el ){
        if ( loadState == 'start' ) {
            el.addClassName( 'loading' );
            el.disable();
            el.select('span span')[0].innerHTML = "please wait...";
        } else {
            el.removeClassName( 'loading' );
            el.enable();
            el.select('span span')[0].innerHTML = "buy now";
        }
    });
}
```

If I `console.log()` the element, I get the object (or array) I'm expecting, so I don't know what's wrong.

I've also tried several SO answers, including this one: [Add or remove class with prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324755/add-or-remove-class-with-prototype)

In case it matters, the platform is Magento CE 1.8.0.2. How can I update these button elements using Prototype? Thanks.

### ~ edit ~

There are several HTML elements on the page. They all look like this:

```
<button type="button" title="buy now" class="button btn" onclick="productAddToCart(this)">
    <span><span>Quick Buy</span></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Do you get any console errors? the 2nd block of code looks like it should work. Can you post the HTML you are trying to change?

Comment: Thx Geek, no console errors at all, no server errors either. I've added sample HTML to the question :)

Comment: When is this code running, is it part of the `productAddToCart` function? does it run as well as that method? is there a possibility that the button and spans are reset as soon as they are set (race condition)? Putting the core elements/script into a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Kua47/1/) shows it works, there is something else happening on the page.

Comment: Why didn't I think of jsfiddle!?! Thx for your effort; it's setup a little differently: http://jsfiddle.net/QdqXW/1/ Although the fiddle works! In reality, the second function `customAddProduct` is called on submit of the form. Make sense?

Comment: so the code works by itself - means something else on the page it affecting your elements - you need to do more digging or if possible post a public link to the page you are having a problem at.

Comment: Do you see this behavior in one browser and not another, or does it travel? I have had to put a delay into functions like this in the past, you may want to try that as well. (Observe the submit, stop it with `evt.stop()`, then do your classname change, then send a delayed `this.submit()`.) If this fixes it, it's because the browser stops processing any changes to the DOM after you press Submit -- you're leaving the page, it shouldn't change, therefore.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much to all who contributed. The AJAX request was returning a hyphenated key in the JSON response:

```
{"msg-html":"blah blah blah"}
```

Reading this from the response object as follows was the problem:

```
var ajaxResult = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
var ajaxMsg = ajaxResult.msg-html;
```

Hyphens are not allowed in JSON keys, instead the object needs to be accessed as follows:

```
var ajaxMsg = ajaxResult["msg-html"];
```

... or remove the hyphens! Thanks again to all.

Full credit to this dude/dudette: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/120227/parsing-json-with-hyphenated-key-names